# How do I add a variable from while to switch

Tags: java, string, while-loop, switch-statement

I understand what my IDE is telling me, I can't use the `s1` variable in the switch. I don't understand why or how to fix it.

Based on what I have picked up so far, this is what I'm trying to do:

> Make a fictional machine turn on and off with specific commands and
>   Accept a random string without crashing

A correction to the code would be good. But what I'd really like to know is am I doing something obviously stupid or is what I'm doing not possible?

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Switches {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int myInt = 1;

        while (myInt < 20) {
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

            System.out.println("Please enter a command: ");
            String s1;
            s1 = input.nextLine();

            System.out.println(s1);
        }

        switch (s1) {
        case "start":
            System.out.println("Machine Started!");
            myInt++;
            break;

        case "stop":
            System.out.println("Machine Stopped!");
            myInt++;
            break;

        default:
            System.out.println("Command not recognised!");
        }

        while (myInt > 100)
            ;
        System.out.println("Error");
    }
}
```

---

Here is my revised code:

```java
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Switches {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int myInt = 1;

        do {

            System.out.println("Please enter a command: ");
            String s1;
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            s1 = input.nextLine();

            switch (s1) {
            case "start":
                System.out.println("Machine Started!");
                myInt++;
                break;

            case "stop":
                System.out.println("Machine Stopped!");
                myInt++;
                break;

            default:
                System.out.println("Command not recognised!");
            }
        }

        while (myInt < 100);

    }
}
```

Comment: Don't you want that switch inside your first while? With the current formatting, I see it as unreachable code. You don't increment myInt inside the while, so you won't get out of it.

Answer (score 1):

In this piece of code I see that the variable `myInt` never change:

```
while(myInt < 20){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter a command: ");
    String s1;
    s1 = input.nextLine();

    System.out.println(s1);
}
```

Where are you changing that variable? because you are doing an infinite loop, that variable always going to be 1 and never going to reach the switch

Answer (score 1):

You're defining s1 inside the the while loop but accessing after the loop, so it doesn't exist outside the loop. Just define s1 before the while loop and you should be good. Like:

```
int myInt = 1;
String s1;

while(myInt < 20){
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Please enter a command: ");
    s1 = input.nextLine();

    System.out.println(s1);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The last while-loop is also an endless loop if myInt is smaller than 100. The semicolon directly after the while-loop doesn't make sense.